# How to enable NPAPI option in google chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I have enter following link in URL in chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
```

But after hitting above line in URL can not see the option to enable NPAPI. I have tried same thing in Windows and in MAC and I found option to enable NPAPI. Can anyone tell me how can I enable it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

April 2014: NPAPI support was removed from Chrome for Linux in release 35.